# Bash: how to make telnet or nc work in background until connection is closed

Tags: bash, telnet, netcat

Below I am describing what I was struggling with and the decision that I came to currently. **Please point me to the cleverer/smaller decisions, also would be glad to receive feedback**.

So, there are a publisher and a client on a localhost, they communicate through port 8080. I can telnet or nc to this port and write output to a log normally, but cannot make the same commands work in background.

What I see is that when launched in background they stop immediately after getting the first input (***is it really so?***), but in foreground they work as they should and die only after publisher closes connection at this port.

This is what occurs normally:

```
> telnet localhost 8080 | tee output.log (or >>output.log, no matter)
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Publisher starts sending information via port.

```
***some necessary output***
```

Publisher closes the port.

```
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

But when launched in background it stops immediately, without waiting for output:

```
> nohup telnet localhost 8080 | tee output.log (or <command> &, or nohup <command> &)
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use a netcat command instead :

```
nohup nc -d localhost 8080 >>console-8080.txt &
```

If you want to indent the log file with the date :

```
nohup nc -d localhost 8080 | while read line ; do echo `date +'%d%m%Y-%H%M%S'`: $line >>console-8080.txt; done &
```

To restart nc process in case it closes :

```
#!/bin/bash
ip=$1
port=$2
while [ 1 ]
do
    nc -d $ip $port | while read line ; do echo `date +'%d%m%Y-%H%M%S'`: $line >>console-$ip-$port.txt; done
    sleep .1
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an expect script that I`ve come to. It is being launched in background.

```
nohup ./telnet_expect.sh &
```

The script spawns new bash session and performs usual redirection to a file.

Usually I arrange communicating between bash and expect via env variables, here I have not implemented it because the whole use case is small enough.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "\n$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S,%3N) -- Started telnet_expect.sh\n"

logFile="/export/home/<user>/<folder>/output.log"
logFileExpect="/export/home/<user>/<folder>/expect.log"

echo > "$logFile"
echo > "$logFileExpect"

until nc -w 1 localhost 8080
do
    sleep 1
done

expect -c "
log_user 1
set timeout 250

proc err_exit {msg} {
        puts \"---\"
    puts stderr \"\$msg\"
        send \"exit status: \$?\r\"
    exit 1
}

exp_internal -f /export/home/<user>/<folder>/expect.log 1

spawn bash

send \"telnet localhost 8080 >> /export/home/<user>/<folder>/output.log\r\"
sleep 10
expect {
    \"*onnection closed by foreign host*\" {
        send \"echo Success\r\"
    }
    timeout {
        err_exit \"\nError: timeout\n\"
    }
}

send \"exit\r\"

expect eof
"

echo -e "\n$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S,%3N) -- Finished telnet_expect.sh\n"
```

Upd: below is more configurable version which takes log file as an argument. This is how to launch:

```
nohup ./telnet_expect.sh <your_output_log_file> &
```

The values of IP and  port here are defined only once, so it is easy to move them to arguments as well. Also there are debug log and console log to understand what exactly is going on. User can provide either absolute or relative path to a log file.

```
#!/bin/bash

scriptFolderPath=$(dirname $(readlink -f "$0"))
logDir="$scriptFolderPath"
logFileDefault="$logDir"/"output_default.log"
logFileExpect="$logDir"/"expect.log"
ip="localhost"
port="8080"

logConsole="$logDir"/"console_telnet.log"
echo > "$logConsole"

echo -e "\n$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S,%3N) -- Started telnet_expect.sh\n" >> "$logConsole"

### debug info
logDebug="$logDir"/"debug_telnet.log"
echo > "$logDebug"
exec 5> "$logDebug"
BASH_XTRACEFD="5"
PS4='$LINENO: '
set -x

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    logFile="$logFileDefault"
else
    if [[ $logFile =~ "/" ]]; then
        logFile="$1"
    else
        echo "Got the log file in the same folder as the script" >> "$logConsole"
        logFile="$scriptFolderPath"/"$1"
    fi
fi

echo > "$logFile"
echo > "$logFileExpect"

### setting envs
echo -e "\nsetting BCKGR_TELNET_LOG" >> "$logConsole"
export BCKGR_TELNET_LOG="$logFile"
echo "set BCKGR_TELNET_LOG: $BCKGR_TELNET_LOG" >> "$logConsole"

echo -e "\nsetting BCKGR_TELNET_LOG_EXPECT" >> "$logConsole"
export BCKGR_TELNET_LOG_EXPECT="$logFileExpect"
echo -e "set BCKGR_TELNET_LOG_EXPECT: $BCKGR_TELNET_LOG_EXPECT\n" >> "$logConsole"

echo -e "\nsetting BCKGR_TELNET_LOG_PORT" >> "$logConsole"
export BCKGR_TELNET_LOG_PORT="$port"
echo -e "set BCKGR_TELNET_LOG_PORT: $BCKGR_TELNET_LOG_PORT\n" >> "$logConsole"

echo -e "\nsetting BCKGR_TELNET_LOG_IP" >> "$logConsole"
export BCKGR_TELNET_LOG_IP="$ip"
echo -e "set BCKGR_TELNET_LOG_IP: $BCKGR_TELNET_LOG_IP\n" >> "$logConsole"

until nc -w 1 "$ip" "$port"
do
    sleep 1
done

expect -c "
log_user 1
set timeout 250

proc err_exit {msg} {
        puts \"---\"
    puts stderr \"\$msg\"
        send \"exit status: \$?\r\"
    exit 1
}

puts \"Reading BCKGR_TELNET_LOG_EXPECT\"

if {[info exists env(BCKGR_TELNET_LOG_EXPECT)]} {
    set bckgr_telnet_log_expect $::env(BCKGR_TELNET_LOG_EXPECT)
        puts \"Found BCKGR_TELNET_LOG_EXPECT\"
} else {
        err_exit \"Error while reading env variable BCKGR_TELNET_LOG_EXPECT\"
}

puts \"Reading BCKGR_TELNET_LOG\"

if {[info exists env(BCKGR_TELNET_LOG)]} {
    set bckgr_telnet_log $::env(BCKGR_TELNET_LOG)
        puts \"Found BCKGR_TELNET_LOG\"
} else {
        err_exit \"Error while reading env variable BCKGR_TELNET_LOG\"
}

puts \"Reading BCKGR_TELNET_LOG_PORT\"

if {[info exists env(BCKGR_TELNET_LOG_PORT)]} {
    set bckgr_telnet_log_port $::env(BCKGR_TELNET_LOG_PORT)
        puts \"Found BCKGR_TELNET_LOG_PORT\"
} else {
        err_exit \"Error while reading env variable BCKGR_TELNET_LOG_PORT\"
}

puts \"Reading BCKGR_TELNET_LOG_IP\"

if {[info exists env(BCKGR_TELNET_LOG_IP)]} {
    set bckgr_telnet_log_ip $::env(BCKGR_TELNET_LOG_IP)
        puts \"Found BCKGR_TELNET_LOG_IP\"
} else {
        err_exit \"Error while reading env variable BCKGR_TELNET_LOG_IP\"
}

exp_internal -f \$bckgr_telnet_log_expect 1

spawn bash

send \"telnet \$bckgr_telnet_log_ip \$bckgr_telnet_log_port >> \$bckgr_telnet_log\r\"
sleep 10
expect {
    \"*onnection closed by foreign host*\" {
        send \"echo Success\r\"
    }
    timeout {
        err_exit \"\nError: timeout\n\"
    }
}

send \"exit\r\"

expect eof
"

echo -e "\nUnsetting env variables" >> "$logConsole"
unset BCKGR_TELNET_LOG
unset BCKGR_TELNET_LOG_EXPECT
unset BCKGR_TELNET_LOG_PORT
unset BCKGR_TELNET_LOG_IP

echo -e "\n$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S,%3N) -- Finished telnet_expect.sh\n" >> "$logConsole"
```